# How do I configure Spring and SLF4J so that I can get logging?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

I've got a maven & spring app that I want logging in. I'm keen to use SLF4J.

I want to put all my config files into a directory {classpath}/config including log4j.xml and then init using a spring bean.

e.g.

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/log4j.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However I get this warning and no logging.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I've googled around and can't find a simple example on setting this up. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing. Does it work any different if you try a complete path
*<value>C:/config/log4j.xml</value>*

Comment: Nope. Hard coding doesn't help. =(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In addition to Jatin's answer:

Spring uses Jakarta Commons Logging as a logging API. In order to log to slf4j, you need to make sure `commons-logging` is not on the classpath. `jcl-over-slf4j` is a replacement jar for commons-logging.

If you're using maven, you can detect where commons-logging comes from using `mvn dependency:tree` and exclude it from all dependencies that require it using dependency exclusions. You might need to run `mvn dependency:tree` several times though, because it only shows the first occurence of a transitive dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I like the third approach suggested here - http://slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL - using empty artifacts.  This option is recommended in the current version of the Spring Reference manual.

Answer (score 27):

You'll find an example at https://github.com/mbogoevici/spring-samples/tree/master/mvc-basic/trunk.  You need to include some dependencies in your POM file to enable logging.

```
<!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The example has the log4j config file directly in the classpath, not under a config directory which is what I'd like.

Comment: Actually that did help a bit though. I've now got logging in my app, It's just spring that's complaining.

Comment: If a particular class is complaining you need to add the required package to the list of packaged registered with the logger. 

You can also put it in a config folder and add that folder to the class path.

Comment: I think the warning is start up only. Once the log4j configurer bean has run I'm getting all the logging I need.

Would be nice to be able to make the warning go away, but I think I'm ok to leave it.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completeness, a `logback-classic` variant:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do not forget however to **disable `commons-logging` dependency** which sprouts from Spring dependency like in the accepted (Stijn's) answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use blow configuration for implementation of the `JCL API` on the `classpath`:

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.14</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

for More information check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

keep log4j file in default package

Answer (score 1):

I like the logback way, and for slf4j, we do the similar config:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

slf4j-log4j12 will automatically introduce slf4j-api and log4j, so don't need to put so many dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Just add `lazy-init="false"` to eagerly load the bean for log4j configuration in your root context. That should solve the WARN message `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger`

Example:

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
```

A more better approach would be to have the configuration in web.xml or as a JVM parameter (`-Dlog4j.configuration=.../conf/log4j.xml` or with 'file:' prefix as `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties` for some cases)