# How to chain Guava futures?

Tags: java, guava, future

I'm trying to create a small service to accept file upload, unzip it and then delete the uploaded file. Those three steps should be chained as futures. I'm using Google Guava library.

Workflow is:

A future to download the file, if the operation completed, then a future to unzip the file. If unzipping is done, a future to delete the original uploaded file.

But honestly, it isn't clear to me how I would chain the futures, and even how to create them in Guava's way. Documentation is simply terse and unclear. Ok, there is `transform` method but no concrete example at all. `chain` method is deprecated.

I miss `RxJava` library.

Comment: Futures do not do work. Runnables do.

Comment: @BrettOkken How to chain runnable in Guava's way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to chain async calls using Guava?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191891/is-it-possible-to-chain-async-calls-using-guava)

Comment: What's wrong with [`Futures.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor%29) ?

Comment: The `CompletableFuture` in java 8 also provides some similar functionality. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: @LouisWasserman Unclear to me how to create a Guava future without `submit()` method of executor.

Comment: Are you lpoking for ListenableFutureTask?

Answer (score 3):

`Futures.transform` is not fluently chainable like RxJava, but you can still use it to set up `Future`s that depend on one another. Here is a concrete example:

```
final ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

final ListenableFuture<FileClass> fileFuture = service.submit(() -> fileDownloader.download())
final ListenableFuture<UnzippedFileClass> unzippedFileFuture = Futures.transform(fileFuture, 
      //need to cast this lambda
      (Function<FileClass, UnzippedFileClass>) file -> fileUnzipper.unzip(file));
final ListenableFuture<Void> deletedFileFuture = Futures.transform(unzippedFileFuture, 
      (Function<UnzippedFileClass, Void>) unzippedFile -> fileDeleter.delete(unzippedFile));
deletedFileFuture.get(); //or however you want to wait for the result
```

This example assumes `fileDownloader.download()` returns an instance of `FileClass`, `fileUpzipper.unzip()` returns an `UnzippedFileClass` etc. If `FileDownloader.download()` instead returns a `ListenableFuture<FileClass>`, use `AsyncFunction` instead of `Function`.

This example also uses Java 8 lambdas for brevity. If you are not using Java 8, pass in anonymous implementations of Function or AsyncFunction instead:

```
Futures.transform(fileFuture, new AsyncFunction<FileClass, UpzippedFileClass>() {
        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<UnzippedFileClass> apply(final FileClass input) throws Exception {
            return fileUnzipper.unzip();
        }
    });
```

More info on `transform` here: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform (scroll or search for "transform" -- deep linking appears to be broken currently)

Answer (score 2):

Guava extends the `Future` interface with `ListenableFuture` for this purpose.

Something like this should work:

```
Runnable downloader, unzipper;
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

service.submit(downloader).addListener(unzipper, service);
```

I would include deleting the file in the unzipper, since it is a near instantaneous action, and it would complicate the code to separate it.