# RestTemplate logging POST data

Tags: spring, log4j, resttemplate

my resttemplate.exchange() failed on a POST request, with the server returning a 500 error.

I tried to set the root logging level to DEBUG, but nothing was logged before the 500 error was returned. to make sure that my logging config is right, I added a line before the resttemplate call

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.execute(new HttpGet("http://google.com"));
```

in this case indeed a lot of logging messages appeared.

so how can I make RestTemplate export the debugging data?

Thanks
Yang

Answer (score 11):

From your analysis it seems that you expect RestTemplate to use Apache HttpClient.

However, by default, Spring RestTemplate does not use Apache HttpClient but uses the JDK facilities (java.net.URL#openConnection() etc.) by means of SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.

[org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/HttpAccessor.html) declares:

```
private ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
```

As far as I know, this client does not support logging requests/responses.

To change RestTemplate to use HttpClient, try this:

```
new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Logging configuration should then enable category `org.apache.http.wire` at level `debug` for complete requests/responses to be logged.

Comment: Not sure if this is version dependent, but setting debug for org.apache.http.wire does not work on Spring RestTemplate for me.