# Logging all network traffic in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, slf4j

I have spring mvc application using RequestBody and ResponseBody annotations. They are configured with MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. I also have slf4j set up. I would like to log all json as it comes in and out from my controller. 
 I did extend

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

@Override
public Object read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    logStream(inputMessage.getBody());
    return super.read(type, contextClass, inputMessage);
}
```

I can get the input stream, but if I read the content it becomes empty and I loose the message. Moreover mark() and reset() is not supported. It is implemented by PushbackInputStream, so I tried to read it's content and push it back like this:

```
public void logStream(InputStream is) {
    if (is instanceof PushbackInputStream)
    try {
        PushbackInputStream pushbackInputStream = (PushbackInputStream) is;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20000];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(is.available());
        int red = is.read();
        int pos =0;
        while (red > -1) {
            bytes[pos] = (byte) red;
            pos=1 + pos;
            red = is.read();
        }
        pushbackInputStream.unread(bytes,0, pos-1);
        log.info("Json payload " + sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ignoring exception in logger ", e);
    }
}
```

but I get exception

```
java.io.IOException: Push back buffer is full
```

I also tried to turn on logging on http level as described here:[Spring RestTemplate - how to enable full debugging/logging of requests/responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses) without luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more than whole work day of experimenting I got working solution. 
It consists of Logging filter, two wrappers for request and response and registration of Logging filter:

the filter class is:

```
/**
 * Http logging filter, which wraps around request and response in
 * each http call and logs
 * whole request and response bodies. It is enabled by 
 * putting this instance into filter chain
 * by overriding getServletFilters() in  
 * AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.
 */
public class LoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class);

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    RequestLoggingWrapper requestLoggingWrapper = new RequestLoggingWrapper(id, request);
    ResponseLoggingWrapper responseLoggingWrapper = new ResponseLoggingWrapper(id, response);
    log.debug(id + ": http request " + request.getRequestURI());
    super.doFilterInternal(requestLoggingWrapper, responseLoggingWrapper, filterChain);
    log.debug(id + ": http response " + response.getStatus() + " finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - id) + "ms");
}

@Override
protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {

}

@Override
protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {

}
}
```

this class is using stream wrappers, which was suggested by 
Master Slave and David Ehrmann.

Request wrapper looks like this:

```
/**
 * Request logging wrapper using proxy split stream to extract request body
 */
public class RequestLoggingWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
private static final Logger log =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestLoggingWrapper.class);
private final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private long id;

/**
 * @param requestId and id which gets logged to output file. It's used to bind request with
 *                  response
 * @param request   request from which we want to extract post data
 */
public RequestLoggingWrapper(Long requestId, HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.id = requestId;
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ServletInputStream servletInputStream = RequestLoggingWrapper.super.getInputStream();
    return new ServletInputStream() {
        private TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(servletInputStream, bos);

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return tee.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return tee.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return tee.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return servletInputStream.isFinished();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return servletInputStream.isReady();
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
            servletInputStream.setReadListener(readListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            // do the logging
            logRequest();
        }
    };
}

public void logRequest() {
    log.info(getId() + ": http request " + new String(toByteArray()));
}

public byte[] toByteArray() {
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

and response wrapper is different only in close/flush method (close doesn't get called)

```
public class ResponseLoggingWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseLoggingWrapper.class);
private final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private long id;

/**
 * @param requestId and id which gets logged to output file. It's used to bind response with
 *                  response (they will have same id, currenttimemilis is used)
 * @param response  response from which we want to extract stream data
 */
public ResponseLoggingWrapper(Long requestId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
    this.id = requestId;
}

@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    final ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = ResponseLoggingWrapper.super.getOutputStream();
    return new ServletOutputStream() {
        private TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(servletOutputStream, bos);

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            tee.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            tee.write(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            tee.flush();
            logRequest();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            tee.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return servletOutputStream.isReady();
        }

        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
            servletOutputStream.setWriteListener(writeListener);
        }


        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            // do the logging
            logRequest();
        }
    };
}

public void logRequest() {
    byte[] toLog = toByteArray();
    if (toLog != null && toLog.length > 0)
        log.info(getId() + ": http response " + new String(toLog));
}

/**
 * this method will clear the buffer, so
 *
 * @return captured bytes from stream
 */
public byte[] toByteArray() {
    byte[] ret = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.reset();
    return ret;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

at last LoggingFilter needs to be registered in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer like this:

```
 @Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    LoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter = new LoggingFilter();

    return new Filter[]{requestLoggingFilter};
}
```

I know, there is maven lib for this, but I don't want to include whole lib because of small logging utility. It was much harder than I originally thought. I expected to achieve this just by modifying log4j.properties. I still think this should be part of Spring.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to decorate `HttpInputMessage` so it returns a decorated `InputStream` that logs all reads in an internal buffer, then on `close()` or `finalize()` logs what was read.

Here's an InputStream that will capture what was read:

```
  public class LoggingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

      private ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      private boolean logged = false;

      protected LoggingInputStream(InputStream in) {
          super(in);
      }

      @Override
      protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
          try {
              this.log();
          } finally {
              super.finalize();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void close() throws IOException {
          try {
              this.log();
          } finally {
              super.close();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
          int r = super.read();
          if (r >= 0) {
              out.write(r);
          }
          return r;
      }

      @Override
      public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
          int read = super.read(b);
          if (read > 0) {
              out.write(b, 0, read);
          }
          return read;
      }

      @Override
      public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
          int read = super.read(b, off, len);
          if (read > 0) {
              out.write(b, off, read);
          }
          return read;
      }

      @Override
      public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
          long skipped = 0;
          byte[] b = new byte[4096];
          int read;
          while ((read = this.read(b, 0, (int)Math.min(n, b.length))) >= 0) {
              skipped += read;
              n -= read;
          }
          return skipped;
      }

      private void log() {
          if (!logged) {
              logged = true;
              try {
                  log.info("Json payload " + new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { }
          }
      }
  }
```

And now

```
@Override
public Object read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, final HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    return super.read(type, contextClass, new HttpInputMessage() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getBody() {
            return new LoggingInputStream(inputMessage.getBody());
        }
        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            return inputMessage.getHeaders();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorating `HttpInputMessage` as David Ehrmann suggested is one likely solution.

The whole trouble with this functionality is that it requires `InputStream` to be read more than once. However, this is not possible, once you read a portion or a stream, its "consumed" and there no way to go back and read it again.

A typical solution is to apply a filter that will create a wrapper for a request that will allow re-reads of the `inputStream`. One approach is by using the [TeeInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) which copies all the bytes read from `InputStream` to a secondary `OutputStream`.

There's a github project that uses just that kind of a filter and in fact just for the same purpose [spring-mvc-logger](https://github.com/isrsal/spring-mvc-logger) The `RequestWrapper` class used

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private long id;


    public RequestWrapper(Long requestId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.id = requestId;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            private TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(RequestWrapper.super.getInputStream(), bos);

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return tee.read();
            }
        };
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray(){
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

A similar implementation wraps the response as well

Comment: Trying to use this but without luck. Overriding doFilterInternal() in CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, where replacing filter, adding this AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, filter gets instantiated, but not invoking doFilterInternal

Comment: I finally got it working. I needed to implement more methods in ServletInputStream like David Ehrmann sugested.  In response method close() does not get called, so I hooked to flush() which gets called 3 times, so I needed to make sure it will log only once.