# how to view network traffic for tomcat and spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Using Spring 2.0.3
I would like to know how to configure tomcat so as to view the network traffic. I have looked at [Logging all network traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942818/logging-all-network-traffic-in-spring-mvc)

but the solution there requires much coding would like to avoid. I am looking for some setting which would output what is sent over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what usually is considered network traffic. Those solutions are to intercept the Java stream used for the HTTP traffic of Spring MVC. You mention using Spring but not Spring MVC explicitly. In any case to capture network traffic without any coding you could use a packet capture tool, like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Note that you will not be able to decrypt HTTPS out of the box. It requires some [extra configurations and access to secret keys](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/).

Another option for HTTP traffic is to enable [Java SSL debug log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html). It can be very verbose but you don't need extra steps or learn a new tool.