# How do I debug RestTemplate using Logback in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, logback

I've been trying to figure out what I'm missing with my `RestTemplate` setup (particularly `OAuth2RestTemplate`) so I want to see the logs for debugging. I found [one possible solution for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964142/404604), but nothing about the operation of the `RestTemplate` gets shown.

What I've done so far is to replace the default Logback logging mechanism in my Spring Boot app by following [the configuration shown here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging). When I run my Spring Boot application after changing the logging dependencies, all I see on the console is the Spring logo (in ASCII) and nothing else. I've already defined a `log4j-spring.properties` in `src/main/resources` with the property defined in the previous link.

What else am I missing here? Do I need to run my Spring Boot app in debug mode? If so, how do I do that? Also, how do I set this up using the default Logback mechanism?

Comment: Why would you need log4j for that? Just add `logging.level.org.springframework.web.client=DEBUG` to your `application.properties`. Don't make it more complicated then that, just use logback (at least don't use log4j as that is deprecated).

Comment: Hence the question. The best reference I can find is the StackOverflow answer I linked to, which describes how to do it in log4j. Now, I'm asking how to do the same thing in Logback.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: See the comment... You can do it regardless WHICH logging framework by simply adding it to the `application.properties`. Also instead of asking a question on how to enable logging you might want to ask a question what is wrong with your setup for the `RestTemplate`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses/47467572