# Request working in curl but not in RestTemplate

Tags: spring, curl, resttemplate

The following call in curl is working and the server response is a 200 code:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cookie: wv_sess=emrri58a7f3qauof5ntfsc77k7" -X GET http://192.168.1.1/cli/aos?cmd=show+interfaces+1/1/1
```

But when i try doing the same with RestTemplate in Spring with the following code:

```
        String cookies = "wv_sess=emrri58a7f3qauof5ntfsc77k7";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Cookie",cookies);
        headers.set("Content-Type",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://192.168.1.1/cli/aos?cmd=show+interfaces+1/1/1", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        logger.info(response.toString());
```

i get a 400 code so it makes HttpClient crash:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request] with root cause
```

What is the equivalent from the curl sentence to RestTemplate?
Does someone have any suggestion to fix it?

NOTE: I making requests to WebServices from an Alcatel 6860 switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks anyway for the replies.

**The problem was that RestTemplate was encoding my URL, i detected it via Wireshark.**

Given the original URL:

```
http://192.168.1.1/cli/aos?cmd=show+interfaces+1/1/1
```

it got replaced the "+" symbol and the following was the result:

```
http://192.168.1.1/cli/aos?cmd=show%2Binterfaces%2B1/1/1
```

So the server of course detected an invalid URL and have to answer with a 400 code error.

To fix it i replaced the symbol "+" for a space which encoded is a "+".

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it for me. I was sending requests to Salesforce Rest API and it was failing in RestTemplate and successful in CURL. I just had to replace the '+'s with spaces in my Query.

Answer (score 0):

From your error:

```
nested exception is 
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

it looks like your request is going through, and the server is responding with a 400 Bad Request. Spring RestTemplate throws an [`HttpClientErrorException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html) whenever the server returns a 4xx error code.

Comment: So, what I doing different in RestTemplate that makes it not working?
Maybe the problem is in the Content-Type attribute but I tried lots of combinations for it and still not working.

Comment: Have you tried logging out the full request you're making? Do something like what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620168/530728 . That should help you determine what the difference is between your curl request and your RestTemplate request.

Comment: Why a server returns a 400 Bad Request status depends completely on the server ... Can you enable verbose logs in the server or anything like that?

Comment: I tried with the Interceptor but i just get the objects references.