# What is the difference between UniRest and Spring RestTemplate giving an http 400 Bad Request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, unirest, hubspot

What is the difference with **UniRest** and Spring **RestTemplate** which is giving back a 400 Bad Request with apparently **the same header and body sent ?**

I try to reach the HubSpot API to create a BlogPost, but using `RestTemplate` I have a 400 Bad Request error, and using `UniRest` works alright (returns an OK response). However, I do not want to include a library just to make one REST call: I'd rather stick to `RestTemplate`.

---

## The request data I need to send

- **HttpMethod:** `POST`
- **URL:** https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=*****************
- **Header:** `Content-Type: application/json`
- **Body:** (represented by a class instance as `blogpostSendPost` further down)

```
{
  "name": "My first API blog post!",
  "content_group_id": 351076997
}
```

---

## Using `RestTemplate`

Setting up the request:

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<BlogpostSendPost> request = new HttpEntity<>(blogpostSendPost, headers);
log(request.toString()); 
//LOG PRINT: <BlogpostSendPost(name=My first API blog post!, content_group_id=351076997),[Content-Type:"application/json"]>
```

OR in JSON

*The .json() method converts my object in Json like you can see in the logs*

```java
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(blogpostSendPost.toJson(), headers);
log(request.toString()); 
//LOG PRINT: <{"name":"My first API blog post!","content_group_id":"351076997"},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>
```

**With `.postForObject()`: 400 Bad Request**

```java
BlogpostResponsePost answer = restTemplate.postForObject(
                                 "https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=***********",
                                  request, 
                                  BlogpostResponsePost.class);
```

**With `.exchange()`: 400 Bad Request**

```java
BlogpostResponsePost answer = restTemplate.exchange(
                                  "https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=**********",
                                   HttpMethod.POST,
                                   request,
                                   BlogpostResponsePost.class);
```

---

## Using [`UniRest`](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/): OK

```java
HttpResponse<JsonNode> resp = Unirest
        .post("https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=**********")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(blogpostSendPost)
        .asJson();
```

---

I am using PostMan to call my REST SpringBoot Application which is using theses Services : when I am calling the HubSpot API directly from PostMan it works fine, just like with `UniRest` lib.

Thanks for your help guys !!

Comment: If you surround the `RestTemplate` calls with a `try/catch` that checks `RestClientResponseException`, does it enter that `catch`?

Comment: Another thing you could try would be to replace `BlogpostResponsePost answer = restTemplate.exchange(...)` with `ResponseEntity<BlogpostResponsePost> answer = restTemplate.exchange(...)` and then extract the information from `answer` appropriately.

Comment: Another possibility: if the `POST` is actually trying to create a resource, then maybe you tried with `Unirest` in the first place, which worked fine, and *then* tried with `RestTemplate`, which returned an error because the ID was already taken?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the `RestTemplate` instance before calling the `exchange` method ? Also, you can try adding some more logging to see what is going on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses

Comment: Oh and doesn't the call to `exchange` should return a `ResponseEntity<BlogpostResponsePost>` ?

Comment: Could you provide exactly the error message/exception that you encounter ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Getting-400-Bad-Request-when-trying-to-add-a-Blog-Post/td-p/306532

Instead of converting request object to json, pass request object directly. It worked for me.

// TRY 1: CONTACTS - RestTemplate - OK - contact is created (API V1)

HttpEntity request1 = new HttpEntity<>(contactSendList, headers);
ContactResponseInformations answer1 = restTemplate
.postForObject(
HubSpotConfiguration.URL_CREATE_CONTACT,
request1,
ContactResponseInformations.class);
log.info(answer1.toString());  // OK

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137438)