# REST API call from spring boot not working

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to fetch live data from NSE options trading. Below code is not working and the request made is stuck without any response.
Any workaround on this?

```
public void getLiveBankNiftyData() {
        String RESOURCE_PATH = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY";
        ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(RESOURCE_PATH, Object[].class);
        Object[] objects = responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

Comment: Accessing the URL returns a 401. I think you must provide some security credentials

Comment: @SimonMartinelli :   I am getting data when I directly hit below URL in browser.... https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY

Comment: Did you login on this page in the browser?

Comment: This page does not require any login.

Comment: Try to use an URI for the call like `URI uri = new URI(RESOURCE_PATH);` and then call `restTemplate.getForEntity(uri ...`

Comment: You could also use some extra logging for your restTemplate like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses

Comment: Anyway, I get: `Resource not found` if browsing your URL you've provided in your code.

Comment: @JanosVinceller : For me that URL is working fine in browser and in postman getting 401 and sometimes 200 as well.  I will try extra logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out. Instead of using RestTemplate I used WebClient and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this

```
    // request url
    String url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY";

    // create an instance of RestTemplate
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    // make an HTTP GET request
    String json = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

    // print json
    System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: ranavirkar : Did that work for you? This didn't work for me. I still see the same issue.

Comment: Yes if we directly hit that URl then we get values in postman, But the concern is different here. My code is not able to load the values. Anyways thank you all. I found a way out. Instead of using RestTemplate I used WebClient and this solved the issue.