# Spring boot returns a 404 when calling another API internally

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot API that internally has to call another API and just "forward" the request.

```
private String APIRoot;
public APIInteractionController() {
        this.APIRoot = "<API root here, not showing it because it's private>";
    }
//test if calling API works
@GetMapping("/test")
public String testAPI(){
    logCallAPI(APIRoot);
    String result = callAPI(APIRoot);
    return result;
}
private String callAPI(String uri){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    return result;
}
private void logCallAPI(String uri){
    System.out.println("call API:\nuri: " + uri);
}
```

When I call the endpoint on my sprig boot app, the logger statement gets outputted in the console, but in postmane I just get a 404 even though when I call the API on itself it just returns "hello world" as the root just returns a test string.
Why is this, and how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue I was having here by adding the @ResponseBody annotation to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow answer describes how to enable http wire logging for Spring RestTemplate.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109538/151759) With this enabled, you should be able to see in your logs which URL is actually called and figure out from where, why you receive a 404 return code.